# getting runtime error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick"

Tags: java, android, sqlite, onclick

I'm not familiar with SQlite so I'm not sure if I'm passing incorrect data type to the DBHelper class or what I'm doing wrong.

This is my **logcat**

```
04-16 22:31:07.341 21052-21052/com.example.android.inputtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.inputtest, PID: 21052
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "jordytip": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Tips(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT jordytip INTEGER  mariatip INTEGER )
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1795)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1726)
   at com.example.android.inputtest.MyDBHandler.onCreate(MyDBHandler.java:32)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
   at com.example.android.inputtest.MyDBHandler.addJordyTip(MyDBHandler.java:44)
   at com.example.android.inputtest.MainActivity.submit(MainActivity.java:50)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

This is my **main activity**:

```
package com.example.android.inputtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int jordyTips = 388;
    int mariaTips = 388;
    int more;
    int less;
    EditText tipInput;
    TextView jordyOutput;
    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tipInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipInput);
        jordyOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jordyOutput);
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this,null, null,1);
    }

    public void submit (View view){
        String value= tipInput.getText().toString();
        int newTip =Integer.parseInt(value);

        if (newTip % 2 == 0){
            more = newTip/2;
            less = newTip/2;
        } else {
            more = newTip/2 + 1;
            less = newTip/2;
        }

        if (jordyTips <= mariaTips) {
            jordyTips += more;

            TipData tip = new TipData(more);
            dbHandler.addJordyTip(tip);
            printDatabase();

            mariaTips += less;
        } else {
            jordyTips += less;

            TipData tip = new TipData(less);
            dbHandler.addJordyTip(tip);
            printDatabase();

            mariaTips += more;}

        displayQuantity();
    }

    public void displayQuantity() {
         TextView quantityTextView1 = jordyOutput;
         TextView quantityTextView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mariaOutput);

         quantityTextView1.setText((jordyTips-more)+ "+" + more + " " + String.valueOf(jordyTips));
         quantityTextView2.setText(String.valueOf(mariaTips)+ "+" + less);
     }

     public void printDatabase(){
         String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
         jordyOutput.setText(dbString);
         tipInput.setText("");
     }
}
```

This is my **TipData class**:

```
package com.example.android.inputtest;

/**
* Created by jordy on 4/16/2017.
*/

public class TipData {
    private int _id;
    private int _jordytip;

    public TipData(int jordytip) {
        this._jordytip = jordytip;

    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public void set_jordytip(int _jordytip) {
        this._jordytip = _jordytip;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public int get_jordytip() {
        return _jordytip;
    }
}
```

and this is my **DBHandler class**:

```
package com.example.android.inputtest;

/**
* Created by jordy on 4/16/2017.
*/
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tips.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Tips";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_JORDYTIP = "jordytip";
    public static final String COLUMN_MARIATIP = "mariatip";

    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
                COLUMN_JORDYTIP + " INTEGER  " +
                COLUMN_MARIATIP + " INTEGER " +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addJordyTip(TipData jordytip){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_JORDYTIP,jordytip.get_jordytip() );
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteTip(String jordyTip){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM" + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_JORDYTIP + "=\"" + jordyTip + "\";");
    }

    public String databaseToString(){
        String dbString= "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM" + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE 1";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("jordytip"))!=null){
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("jordytip"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }

        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
}
```

Getting this now:

```
04-17 00:17:58.181 20893-20893/com.example.android.inputtest E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "1": syntax error
04-17 00:17:58.191 20893-20893/com.example.android.inputtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.inputtest, PID: 20893
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "1": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TipsWHERE 1
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1437)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1376)
   at com.example.android.inputtest.MyDBHandler.databaseToString(MyDBHandler.java:63)
   at com.example.android.inputtest.MainActivity.printDatabase(MainActivity.java:83)
   at com.example.android.inputtest.MainActivity.submit(MainActivity.java:51)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

However when I add the space before where

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1";
```

I get "app not responding".

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "jordytip":
>   syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Tips(_id
>   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT jordytip INTEGER  mariatip INTEGER )

At first Rectify **Query**

```
 String query  = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME  + "("
            + COLUMN_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,"
            + COLUMN_JORDYTIP  + " INTEGER ,"
            + COLUMN_MARIATIP  + " INTEGER" + ")";
```

Comment: You might want to explicitly state that the commas are missing in the original code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes sir

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya did it getting this now

Comment: the whole code is too long but here is what i see that is different from logcat  04-16 23:31:39.921 19510-19510/com.example.android.inputtest E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "FROMTipsWHERE": syntax error

Comment: `"DELETE FROM "` add extra space

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya did it getting "04-16 23:52:08.401 5780-5780/com.example.android.inputtest E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "1": syntax error"

Comment: @cerealkiller if you still facing same problem then add your error code in question section

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + KEY_ + " = '"+ get_ID+"'";`

Comment: @cerealkiller did you understand above line ?

Comment: I do not i dont have the KEY_ or get_ID  variables

Comment: @cerealkiller that's  example . your Statement is wrong . are you newbie ??

Comment: You should add `PARAMETER` in your where statement section

Comment: I sadly do not know how to add that

Comment: @cerealkiller okay . I strongly suggest you before writing code at first think . Learn how to pass Parameter .